# How can I deploy an Angular component as a Lib, using different Angular versions? (Each version would yield a package)

Tags: angular

I currently have a bug number of Angular 14 apps published as npm packages.
I also have a great number of applications that consume those packages. Other than that, I've got new applications to be created, and Ideally they would be created using Angular 17 out of the bat.

That said, is there a way I can have my package components published for different versions of Angular? 14 and 17 in my case.
This would allow me to slowly upgrade all my packages and consuming apps, as well as have the new consuming applications running on angular 17 right from the start.

I am really trying to avoid a big-bag approach to this, as updating all packages, and then all consiming applications at once would be crazy.

I am used to do that in C#. E.G. I normally have 2 different .csproj, one in .net6 and another on in .net core. They both point to the same physical files (classses, interfaces, etc) and I just have to build and publish the two projects individually, yelding me 2 diff packages.

I was hoping I could do something simmilar (or better) with Angular but I am having a hard time with that.

Thanks in advance for any tips and hints.

FOr now, I was trying to understand if I could use paths on my tsconfig.json, to map components from one app into the other (see below).

`"paths": { "@angular14package/*":["..MyAngular14Package/src/lib/*"] }` 
I didn't get it to work, but even so, not sure how those would be published as a package. What would the public_api and index files look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a semantic version approach here, you can patch your bugs for the v14 version and publish that to your npm.

After that, you could step by step upgrade your package to v15 and publish that package too and so on for v16, v17...

After this approach is successful you can consume your npm packages in different versions of your angular project.